# In Angular4 WDS disconnected! constantly appear in console

Tags: node.js, angular

I am currently started **Angular 4**. I have come across the following error in the console, which does not show in the terminal:

> [WDS] Disconnected!

[image]

Comment: Its common behaviour when your node server is recompiling

Comment: No it's not common behavior. It's bug. Why it's coming..?

Comment: It is not a bug. When you use ng serve, The browser is constantly connected with server looking for changes. When that server goes down(in case you close the terminal ) It shows you this Message.